# HTML media query min AND max value

Tags: html, css, media-queries

This is my current code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" media="screen and (max-width: 750px)">
```

Is there an option to have a min AND a max query?

I tried `media="screen and (min-width: 250px), screen and (max-width: 750px)"`
but it didn't work.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this way

Make a file for styles route and import other the style file in the @media for any size

example :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px) {
   @import "./example.css";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I will use this.

Answer (score 0):

In style.css there should be a query like this.

**Example**: on screens that are 600px or less, set the background color to olive

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: olive;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply like this.

```
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 767px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    /*  your code here */
    }
```